# How to open "Login Items" in "System Settings" programmatically in MacOS 13 - Ventura?

Tags: macos, applescript, login-items, ventura

I want to open "Login Items" of System Settings in MacOS Ventura(13.0) programatically.

For example, to open "Notifications", i can use the following
url:
x-apple.systempreferences:com.apple.preference.notifications

Programmatically opening login items is what I am looking for

Comment: Have you tried this https://gist.github.com/rmcdongit/f66ff91e0dad78d4d6346a75ded4b751?permalink_comment_id=4258811#gistcomment-4258811 ? I cannot check it because I do not have Ventura installed.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
open x-apple.systempreferences:com.apple.LoginItems-Settings.extension
```

does the trick on macOS Ventura. Found [here](https://gist.github.com/rmcdongit/f66ff91e0dad78d4d6346a75ded4b751?permalink_comment_id=4258811#gistcomment-4258811), where more System Preference pane URLs and paths are collected.

Comment: This method still works in the current beta(s) of macOS Sonoma (14.0).

Answer (score 2):

Two possible methods:

**Method1:** - Thanks to my boss at office (https://developer.apple.com/documentation/servicemanagement/smappservice/4013547-opensystemsettingsloginitems)

```
// Need Xcode 14 
#import <ServiceManagement/ServiceManagement.h>

[SMAppService openSystemSettingsLoginItems];
```

**Method2:** - Thanks @Martin R - Objective C version

```
#import <Appkit/NSWorkspace.h> // Useful for command line application

NSString *url = @"x-apple.systempreferences:com.apple.LoginItems-Settings.extension";
[[NSWorkspace sharedWorkspace] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:url]];
```

[Note: Added my Method2 answer at the same time as @MartinR, without knowing he has answered, but still left it here for people who might be looking for an objective-C version]

(**Edit** Looks like some of the existing links were not opening in Ventura when '''open''' is used, but '''***NSWorkspace.shared.open()***''' works well, the information is from [here](https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/709289)
)

Answer (score 0):

For me, the solution provided by @MartinR yields a syntax error.

While looking for a way to fix this, I stumbled upon this [solution](https://forum.latenightsw.com/t/applescripts-not-working-on-new-system-settings-on-macos-ventura/3986/4). The AppleScript on the following format:

```
use AppleScript version "2.4" -- Yosemite (10.10) or later
use framework "Foundation"
use framework "AppKit"
use scripting additions

current application's NSWorkspace's sharedWorkspace()'s openURL:(current application's NSURL's URLWithString:"x-apple.systempreferences:com.apple.LoginItems-Settings.extension")
```

seems to do the trick.

Additionally, if one wants to find all the possible preference panes in the new System Settings in macOS Ventura, these are listed in the following file:

`/System/Applications/System Settings.app/Contents/Resources/Sidebar.plist`

as found [here](https://gist.github.com/rmcdongit/f66ff91e0dad78d4d6346a75ded4b751?permalink_comment_id=4286386#gistcomment-4286386).